# Oracle Query to Compare dates from Two Different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these two below tables.  One is storing Data Received for an Asset and other one is when the Customer Representative contacted.

Asset_Data_Historical

```
+---------+------------------+
| AssetID | Data_Received_On |
+---------+------------------+
|   17085 | 8/23/2017 22:50  |
|   17085 | 8/25/2017 20:54  |
|   17085 | 8/25/2017 21:08  |
|   17085 | 8/31/2017 18:49  |
|   17085 | 9/29/2017 18:51  |
+---------+------------------+
```

Customer_Contacted_Logs

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+
| TicketID | Asset_ID | Last_Contacted_On |
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|  1785487 |    17085 | 9/28/2017 21:57   |
|  1785491 |    17085 | 10/16/2017 18:51  |
+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

My Problem is:
I need to find the data from the Customer_Contacted_Logs based on the Asset_data_Historical table.

For Example:  for the AssetID 17085, the first Data Received on 8/23/2017 22:50. Now, query has to look into the Customer_Contacted_Logs for the data "Last_Contacted_on" Equal to greater than but not greater than next Data Received_On.

So, in this situation, the First Data received on 8/23/2017 22:50 and it will look for the data in Customer_contacted_log and the finds the date is 9/28/2017 21:57 and the same date will populate as the Contacted date is not greater than Data_Received_on. In the next instance, it will fetch the date 10/16/2017 18:51.

Here is an example, How I would like the query to fetch.

```
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
| AssetID | Data_Received_On | Last_Contacted_On |
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
|   17085 | 8/23/2017 22:50  | 9/28/2017 21:57   |
|   17085 | 8/25/2017 20:54  | 9/28/2017 21:57   |
|   17085 | 8/25/2017 21:08  | 9/28/2017 21:57   |
|   17085 | 8/31/2017 18:49  | 9/28/2017 21:57   |
|   17085 | 9/29/2017 18:51  | 10/16/2017 18:51  |
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Please let me know,  if any questions.

Thank you In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `correlated subquery`

```
with Asset_Data_Historical(AssetID, Data_Received_On) as
(
  select 17085, timestamp'2017-08-23 22:50:00' from dual union all
  select 17085, timestamp'2017-08-25 20:54:00' from dual union all 
  select 17085, timestamp'2017-08-25 21:08:00' from dual union all 
  select 17085, timestamp'2017-08-31 18:49:00' from dual union all  
  select 17085, timestamp'2017-09-29 18:51:00' from dual    
), Customer_Contacted_Logs(TicketID, Asset_ID, Last_Contacted_On ) as
(
  select 1785487,17085, timestamp'2017-09-28 21:57:00' from dual union all
  select 1785491,17085, timestamp'2017-10-16 18:51:00' from dual
)
select a.*, 
      ( select min(c.Last_Contacted_On)
          from Customer_Contacted_Logs c 
         where a.AssetID = c.Asset_ID
           and a.Data_Received_On < c.Last_Contacted_On )
       as Last_Contacted_On
  from Asset_Data_Historical a;


ASSETID   DATA_RECEIVED_ON      LAST_CONTACTED_ON
17085     23.08.2017 22:50:00   28.09.2017 21:57:00
17085     25.08.2017 20:54:00   28.09.2017 21:57:00
17085     25.08.2017 21:08:00   28.09.2017 21:57:00
17085     31.08.2017 18:49:00   28.09.2017 21:57:00
17085     29.09.2017 18:51:00   16.10.2017 18:51:00
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YWR60251)</kbd>